# Obtaining simple metrics from NS3 like throughput vs time, packet loss vs time

Tags: c++, ns-3

I'm never used NS3 before and I have a school assignment to plot throughput vs time and packet loss vs time. I know that just by running fifth.cc I'll get the congestion window data. I noticed I can see all the instances where a packet was dropped and I manipulated that data in MATLAB to plot packet loss vs time there. How would I go about to create a piece of code that would be able to plot these 2 graphs? 
The topology is a simple TCP source and a TCP sink.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NS-3 provides a `gnuplot` library that you can use to plot what you want.
See reference [here](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/manual/html/gnuplot.html) (with examples).

There are also plenty of other examples of how to accomplish this. Take a look at the NS-3 Users mailing list on Google Groups.